# Sql query for creating message list

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am creating a message service with Laravel.

I want to display recent messages from all based on time. This is what I am trying to implement [image: This is Im trying to implement]

The following are my tables

- **message table

  [image: message table]**
- **message_user table

  [image: message_user tbale]**

I tried the following code

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id,sender 
FROM ( 
    SELECT DISTINCT message_user.user_id, messages.sender, messages.created_at 
        FROM messages 
        JOIN message_user ON message_user.message_id=messages.id AND message_user.user_id=225
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT message_user.user_id, messages.sender, messages.created_at FROM messages 
        JOIN message_user ON message_user.message_id=messages.id AND messages.sender=225 AND message_user.user_id NOT IN (
            SELECT DISTINCT messages.sender 
                FROM messages 
                JOIN message_user ON message_user.message_id=messages.id AND message_user.user_id=225
            )
) mytable 
ORDER BY created_at
```

The problem is that the output is not in the expected format (that is not sorted based on created_at)

Following is the corresponding Laravel code I have tried

```
$id        = $request->user()->id;
$user      = User::find($id);
$buddylist = $user->messages()->select(DB::raw('message_user.user_id,messages.sender,messages.created_at'));
$subquery  = Message::select(DB::raw(' messages.sender'))->join('message_user','messages.id','=','message_user.message_id') ->where("message_user.user_id",'=',$request->user()->id);
$mybuddy   = Message::selectRaw('message_user.user_id,messages.sender,messages.created_at')
          ->join('message_user','messages.id','=','message_user.message_id')
          ->where("messages.sender",'=',$request->user()->id)
          ->whereNotIn('message_user.user_id', $subquery)
          ->union( $buddylist)
          ->groupBy('sender')
          ->groupBy('user_id')
          ->orderBy('created_at','desc')
          ->get();
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have another column named 'receiver_id' what you could do is:

```
$query="select * from messages WHERE sender_id='user_id' or receiver_id='user_id' ORDER BY created_at asc";
```

Comment: im trying to create sender list not all messages.if i use your query i didn't get

Comment: i want to get this sender list not all messages https://imgur.com/a/0UCj29M

Comment: do you want to get list of user_id of users who sent message to admin?

Comment: yes and wise versa but not repeat the user_id sender combination

Comment: select DISTINCT sender_id from messages receiver_id='admin_id' ORDER BY created_at asc

Comment: or do you want to select all message to admin and show in same page ordered by date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186013/discussion-between-reneesh-kurian-and-bash-jr).